# R tidyr spread columns across all categories of a given variable

Tags: r, tidyr, data-manipulation, spread

I'm working on a dataset that looks like this.

```
#Dataframe
df=data.frame(Type=c(1,2,4,5,4,3,3,4,5,1,2,3,2,1,2,3,3,2,1,1,NA),
          Q1=c(1,2,6,8,9,10,2,6,7,4,9,9,1,2,NA,4,3,8,7,6,4),
          Q2=c(1,2,4,NA,8,2,1,2,10,7,5,5,5,8,2,7,4,8,7,5,1))
```

**Context**

The dataframe consists of results from a questionnaire.

The first column, `Type`, refers to the type of employee who answered the questionnaire, where 1 = '`Worker`', 2 = '`Factory Lead`', 3 = '`Administrative Staff`', 4 = '`Middle Management`' & 5 = '`Executive`'

The second and third column (`Q1` & `Q2`) are questions, rated on a scale of 1 = '`Strongly Agree`' to 10 (`Strongly Disagree`).

**What I'm Trying to Achieve**

I'd like to compute the total number of responses per `Type`, based on score.
I have created bins for the scores, and they are -

1) `Low` Agreement - Scores from 0 to 4

2) `Medium` Agreement - Scores of 5 or 6

3) `High` Agreement - Scores of 7 or 8

4) `Very High` Agreement - Scores of 9 or 10

So I'd like to count the number of responses per worker per score bin.

**My Attempt**

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

result=df %>%
gather(Item,response,-1) %>%
filter(!is.na(response)) %>%
group_by(Type,Item) %>%
filter(!is.na(Type)) %>%
summarise(Low=sum(response %in% c(0,1,2,3,4)),
        Medium=sum(response %in% c(5,6)),
        High=sum(response %in% c(7,8)),
        VHigh=sum(response %in% c(9,10)) %>%
spread(Type,-Item)
```

My logic is I use `tidyr` library and first `gather` scores to compute the total responses. Then spread the columns, so that I have the sub-totals by worker and by score category.

For example, for Q1, a column for total responses for `Low-Worker`, then `Medium-Worker`, then `High-Worker`, then `Very High-Worker`, then `Low-Factory Lead`, then `Medium-Factory Lead` .... and so on for all combinations of employees and score categories.

Clearly something is not right in my code.

**Desired Output**

A dataframe with **two rows** (`Q1` & `Q2`) and **20 columns** (for each employee-score combination).

Any help on this would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a data frame of scores

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
df <- data_frame(type=c(1,2,4,5,4,3,3,4,5,1,2,3,2,1,2,3,3,2,1,1,NA),
                 q1=c(1,2,6,8,9,10,2,6,7,4,9,9,1,2,NA,4,3,8,7,6,4),
                 q2=c(1,2,4,NA,8,2,1,2,10,7,5,5,5,8,2,7,4,8,7,5,1))

scores <- data_frame(score = 0:10,
                     scorebin = c(rep("Low", 5),
                                  rep("Medium", 2),
                                  rep("High", 2),
                                  rep("Very High", 2)))
```

Gather the data in long format. Join the scores data frame to add a `scorebin` column. Group by `item`, `type` and `scorebin` and count the number of answers under each group.

```
df2 <- df %>%
    gather(item, score, -type) %>% 
    left_join(scores, by = "score") %>% 
    group_by(item, type, scorebin) %>% 
    summarise(n = n()) %>% 
    unite(employeescore, type, scorebin)
```

Change `employeescore` to a factor with ordered levels
so that they are not displayed in alphabetical order (high, low, medium)
but in the correct order (low, medium, high).

```
employeescoreorder <- scores %>% 
    distinct(scorebin) %>% 
    merge(distinct(df, type)) %>% 
    unite(employeescore, type, scorebin)
df2$employeescore <- factor(df2$employeescore, 
                            levels = employeescoreorder$employeescore)
```

Spread the data frame in wide format to obtain 20 columns.

```
df2 %>% 
    spread(employeescore, n)

# A tibble: 2 x 20
# Groups:   item [2]
   item `1_Low` `1_Medium` `1_High` `2_Low` `2_Medium` `2_High` `2_Very High` `4_Low`
* <chr>   <int>      <int>    <int>   <int>      <int>    <int>         <int>   <int>
1    q1       3          1        1       2         NA        1             1      NA
2    q2       1          1        3       2          2        1            NA       2
# ... with 11 more variables: `4_Medium` <int>, `4_High` <int>, `4_Very High` <int>,
#   `5_High` <int>, `5_Very High` <int>, `3_Low` <int>, `3_Medium` <int>, `3_High` <int>,
#   `3_Very High` <int>, NA_Low <int>, `<NA>` <int>
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

```
 df%>%
   mutate(Type_real=case_when(
             Type==1~"Worker",
             Type==2~"Factory Lead",
             Type==3~"Administrative Staff",
             Type==4~"Middle Management",
             Type==5~"Executive"),
         Score=case_when(
             Q1<5~"Low",
             Q1>=5 & Q1<=6~"Medium",
             Q1>=7 & Q1<=8~"High",
             Q1>8~"Very High"))%>%
   na.omit()%>%
   group_by(Type_real,Score)%>%
   summarise(count=n())
# A tibble: 11 x 3
# Groups:   Type_real [?]
   Type_real            Score     count
   <chr>                <chr>     <int>
 1 Administrative Staff Low           3
 2 Administrative Staff Very High     2
 3 Executive            High          1
 4 Factory Lead         High          1
 5 Factory Lead         Low           2
 6 Factory Lead         Very High     1
 7 Middle Management    Medium        2
 8 Middle Management    Very High     1
 9 Worker               High          1
10 Worker               Low           3
11 Worker               Medium        1
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution similar to Paul Rougieux, but without joins is:

```
df %>% 
  mutate(Type = case_when(Type == 1 ~ "Worker",
                          Type == 2 ~ "Factory Lead",
                          Type == 3 ~ "Administrative Staff",
                          Type == 4 ~ "Middle Management",
                          Type == 5 ~ "Executive")) %>% 
  mutate_at(c("Q1", "Q2"), 
            funs(case_when(. %in% 1:4 ~ "Low",
                           . %in% 5:6 ~ "Medium",
                           . %in% 7:8 ~ "High",
                           . %in% 9:10 ~ "Very High"))) %>%
  gather(Questions, Score, Q1:Q2) %>% 
  unite(Type_Score, Type, Score, sep = "_") %>% 
  count(Questions, Type_Score) %>% 
  spread(Type_Score, n)

# A tibble: 2 x 21
#   Questions `Administrative~ `Administrative~ `Administrative~ `Administrative~ Executive_High Executive_NA `Executive_Very~ `Factory Lead_H~
#   <chr>                <int>            <int>            <int>            <int>          <int>        <int>            <int>            <int>
# 1 Q1                      NA                3               NA                2              2           NA               NA                1
# 2 Q2                       1                3                1               NA             NA            1                1                1
# ... with 12 more variables: `Factory Lead_Low` <int>, `Factory Lead_Medium` <int>, `Factory Lead_NA` <int>, `Factory Lead_Very High` <int>,
#   `Middle Management_High` <int>, `Middle Management_Low` <int>, `Middle Management_Medium` <int>, `Middle Management_Very High` <int>,
#   NA_Low <int>, Worker_High <int>, Worker_Low <int>, Worker_Medium <int>
```